# Difference between "functional programming languages" and "lambda calculus based languages"?

Tags: lambda-calculus, functional-programming

In "Can programming be liberated from the Von Neumann Style?", John Backus states:

> The main reason
>   **FP systems are considerably simpler than** either conventional languages or **lambda-calculus-based languages** is
>   that they use only the most elementary fixed naming
>   system (naming a function in a definition) with a simple
>   fixed rule of substituting a function for its name.

What surprises me about this statement is that I had the perception that functional programming languages are based on lambda-calculus. After reading the article, I still cannot understand this statement.

Comment: "Functional programming" as it is generally used by programmers is not a well-defined term; however, "FP system" is a term that is defined in the paper. It doesn't matter how the term "FP" or "functional programming" is usually used outside of the paper. Most languages described as "functional programming languages" are not like the language FP (i.e. FP systems).

Comment: Actually, I heard the term "functional PL" defined as "PL with functions" (by Peter Van Roy). So Assembly and Forth are not functional, but Pascal and C are.